# Restrict user from downloading particular apps from play store

Tags: android, facebook, google-play

I want to develop one app which tracks what are the applications user downloads from play store.Some particular apps like facebook,whatsApp should not be downloaded to user mobile.Is it possible to create this kind of tracking application in android?

Comment: It might be possible on rooted devices, but you would have to keep an up to date database of the app names and their package names or something. No idea how you would go about doing this, though. Why exactly are you trying to do this?

Comment: I am developing business app.So I don't want user to download social,games kind of app to his/her mobile.

Comment: Maybe you would be better off developing a custom Android distribution, that would be the only reliable way to have such fine-grained control.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can track what gets downloaded, but you can't prevent it.

You could listen for [ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) from PackageManager and either warn the user or have your app "phone home" to tell you about it.